# MySQL structure for 2D array lookup?

Tags: mysql

sIm trying to create a mysql database for looking up in a big dataset. I have a set of data (n number) samples and a list of genes in my data collection and I would like to able to lookup a value based on pairing one sample with one gene. In the the table below I have the data for genes, samples and value, and I would like to know the best way sort set this up on mysql for fast lookup.

In my data I have about 35.000 different genes and an aomunt of samples that can vmay vary between 2000-15000. (I dont have a specific number, because I have finished my data yet.)

```
|------------------------------------------------------|
|                  |     sample1    |      sample2     | 
|------------------|----------------|------------------|
|       gene1      |     value1     |       value2     |
|------------------|----------------|------------------|
|       gene2      |     value3     |       value4     |
|------------------|----------------|------------------|
```

What is the best way to put this data up on a mysql database? The "easiest" way that I thought of right away is just throwing it in the database like in the following output, which seems like it would be a big disaster. How can I approach this correctly?

```
|----------------------------------------- ------------|
|       gene1      |     sample1    |      value1      | 
|------------------|----------------|------------------|
|       gene1      |     sample2    |      value2      |
|------------------|----------------|------------------|
|       gene2      |     sample1    |      value3      |
|------------------|----------------|------------------|
|       gene2      |     sample2    |      value4      |
|------------------|----------------|------------------|
```

Comment: Yes. I think you're on the right track. You would have a column identifying the gene, a column identifying the sample and a column holding the result (value). Why do you think that's a disaster?

Comment: Because I have so much data that it might be to many entries in the database. Isnøt there a more clever way to approach this my having seperate tables and joining them maybe?

Comment: Half a billion rows. You may want to look at partitioning, or you may find you need a more powerful RDBMS than MySQL, but structurally, nothing would change.

Comment: This is not a case when you will benefit from normalization that puts one of the identifying columns into another table and joins. That is used generally to prevent repeating data, but if the data is a short gene name, it's not much worse than repeating some made up gene-ID integer anyway. It looks like the first two columns act as a primary key to the third column, so you need them in this table, and you want to identify them as a key. You may also want to build an extra index on `(sample, gene)` so that you can efficiently look things up by sample too.

Comment: I've used MySQL performantly with tables of up to a billion rows before and I'm not a database expert, so your data should be OK. You're going to have to store the data one way or another. If you move some of it into separate tables, you'll still need an ID column to link the two together (like an integer for the sample ID). If `sample1` and `sample2` are big data types (long strings, complex things) then this will save some space, but really not much. The data is what it is. You may want to consider surveying cloud storage options and alternative database tech.